# Add another button in the title bar in OpenBox

Tags: window-manager, openbox, window-title

I'm using Openbox as a Window Manager in Kubuntu.

I know I can reorder the buttons/label of the title bar through ObConf or by modifying the rc.xml, and editing the "NLDIMC" string.

But I wish to **add** another button.
For my purpose, it's an "always on top" button.
I can provide icons for both/all three states (always on top, normal, always on bottom).

I know I can circumvent the issue, and already done it (right now, I can middle click the "send to all desks" to alternate between the options). But I'm looking for something cleaner, with a responsive icon.

Is it possible ?